# solution to integral of polynomial $\int_{-1}^{1}(\frac{1-\xi}{2}H_1^{e}(t)+\frac{1+\xi}{2}H_2^{e}(t))^{1/3}d\xi$

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

$\int_{-1}^{1}(\frac{1-\xi}{2}H_1^{e}(t)+\frac{1+\xi}{2}H_2^{e}(t))^{1/3}d\xi$

Do you have any ideas how to solve this integral (numerically or analytically)? any good approximations?

Comment: You are integrating with respect to $\zeta$ so the integrand is simply $(a\zeta + b)^{1/3}$ where $a,b$ are some constants (related to $H_1,H_2$) so just substitute $u = a\zeta + b$ and you can integrate it directly.

Comment: Are you sure that you have to integrate with respect to $\zeta$ and not to $t$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing with simpler characters, you need to integrate something which looks like $$I=\int \big(a(1-x)+b(1+x)\big)^{1/3}\,dx=\int\sqrt[3]{x (b-a)+(a+b)}\,dx$$ Change variable $x (b-a)+(a+b)=y$, $x=\frac{a+b-y}{a-b}$, $dx=-\frac{dy}{a-b}$. All of these make $$I=\frac{1}{b-a}\int y^{1/3}\,dy=\frac{3 }{4 (b-a)}y^{4/3}$$ Back to $x$ if you prefer to not recompute the bounds $$I=\frac{3 \big((b-a)x+(a+b)\big)^{4/3}}{4 (b-a)}$$

I am sure that you will easily finish.